# optimize ajax code and don't repeat myself

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is my code I don't want repeat my ajax how can I optimize it ? and then have shorter code?
so i show you just an example here:

```
function for() {
if (forceexs) {
    if (login == "inte") {
        $.ajax({
            url: "index_content.php?mode=ppanel=forgotten&force_mssante=0",
            success: function (html) {
                $(".panel-body").html(i18n.tr(html));
                $("#rpps").focus();
            },
        });
    } else if (login == "ex") {
        $.ajax({
            url: "index.php?mode=nel=forgorce_mssante=1",
            success: function (html) {
                $(".panel-body").html(i18n.tr(html));
                $("#rpps").focus();
            },
        });
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: "index.php?mode=phel=internal_or_external",
            success: function (html) {
                $(".panel-body").html(i18n.tr(html));
                $("#rpps").focus();
            },
        });
    }
} else {
    $.ajax({
        url: "index.php?mode=pel=forgotten",
        success: function (html) {
            $(".panel-body").html(i18n.tr(html));
            $("#rpps").focus();
        },
    });
}
}
```

This is the shortest one more easy to understand

Comment: When you're trying to remove duplication, read your code and separate the pieces that change from the pieces that don't change. In your case, it appears like the only thing that changes is the URL. How could you write this `ajax` call only one time while still giving the URL the freedom to change?

Comment: @Tom so you mean I can not do it ?

Comment: No, you definitely can do it. I'm pointing you in the direction of doing it without doing it for you.

Comment: This question should go on code review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Tom thanks for your edit but when i put this function on the code instead of mine i need to have the url (GETQuery) how can i have that one ?

Comment: @abcd please stop changing the edits. I edited the code to remove the duplicated statement at the bottom. There is no need to have this twice.

Comment: @Cjmarkham Hello i make it ok now

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function ajaxRequest(GETQuery) {
  $.ajax({
    url:'index_content?'+GETQuery,
    success: function(html) { 
      $(".panel-body").html(i18n.tr(html));
      $("#rpps").focus();}
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks good but does not working !!!

Comment: could you please  put the whole code?

Comment: You can call this function instead of `$.ajax({url: "index_content.php?<someGETquery>",success: function (html) {$(".panel-body").html(i18n.tr(html));$("#rpps").focus();},});`,  passing the GET query as the argument.

Comment: so how can I get +GETQuery ?

Comment: At the first case it the `mode=physician&panel=forgotten&force_mssante=0` (so its text after the `?` at the url). [About GET queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).